# How to send message to whatsApp contact Automatically?

Tags: android, message, send, whatsapp

I want to send message to whatsapp from my Android app to specific contact without opening whatsapp app.

Currently i am using the below code to do this task. But this redirect me on whatsApp chat window for that specific number. I have to click send button in whatsApp app to send this message.

But i want to send message on Whatsapp contact in background without interaction of whatsApp app.

Any help would appreciable.

```
        String toNumber = "+91 7889080949"; 
        toNumber = toNumber.replace("+", "").replace(" ", "");

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", toNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: I have the same question how does Google app in android devices do that...? It sends whatsapp messages without opening it...

Comment: I don't think that you can do this. @Xenolion what Google app does this?

Comment: There is an app in android devices called `Google` itself. Open it and Just say **Ok Google** Then say **Send a whatsapp message to Someone**. It just send without opening whatsapp. And when you open whatsapp you will frind your message sent.... I was also suprised with this @lulian

Comment: This is an app on playstore that send message on whatsapp in background, link:- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en&id=tkstudio.wachatbotlite      How it works ?

Comment: Well, it looks like it needs rooted devices to work. Since, Facebook didn't provide a public API for this, you should do it in the classic way. It's saffer that way.

Comment: No, I have used this app. it works fine to send text messages on whatsapp without routing phone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654674/send-message-via-whatsapp-programmatically