# Send message via whatsapp programmatically

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm trying to send messages via **Whatsapp** programmatically, the code works except the user needs to click the send button. I need the app to do everything (all user interactions). One way to do to it as follows .

> Go to Menu Button > Settings > Chats. and check the "Enter is send option"

Here's the code I'm using:

```
protected void sendwts(){
    String smsNumber = "2126123456789"; // E164 format without '+' sign
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test \n");
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to send message programmatically by using WhatsApp, WeChat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774595/android-how-to-send-message-programmatically-by-using-whatsapp-wechat)

Comment: You can only send the user and their message to WhatsApp, you cannot push the buttons for them.

Comment: You can not directly send message without send acknowledgement from user. Whats app does not provide such Feature i think none of app provide such feature unless you are authenticated with a SDK .

Comment: this is the expected behaviour , you can not send msgs directly , user need to click the whatsapp send button

Comment: I know, i want the app to run 24/7 to send some data, the client want to get notified when power loses accures via sms or whtsapp

Comment: Whats App avoids sending the message without the user interaction, that is the good behavior

Comment: There is no API so send messages without user input (there **NEVER** will be, that would be a **very bad** thing, on all social media). Send a real S.M.S. ? Probably could hack it, until they find out....then you get banned ;O). goes against the *spirit * of the app...

Comment: suddenly the answer is coming below. LoL.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can do that ***only*** using the [Accessibility API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) of Android.

The idea is quite simple, you'll actually make Android perform the click on Whatsapp's send button.

So the flow will be:

1. Send a regular message (with the intent you're currently using) with a suffix at the end of your message content such as "`Sent by MY_APP`".
2. Once the text there, your accessibility service will be notified that the `EditText` of whatsapp is filled.
3. If the suffix is present on the `EditText` of whatsapp, Your accessibility service will click on the send button. (this is to avoid performing actions as the user types in naturally a regular message).

Here's an example (which you'll have tweak if you wanna make it more restrictive):

```
public class WhatsappAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent (AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (getRootInActiveWindow () == null) {
            return;
        }

        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat rootInActiveWindow = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.wrap (getRootInActiveWindow ());

        // Whatsapp Message EditText id
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> messageNodeList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId ("com.whatsapp:id/entry");
        if (messageNodeList == null || messageNodeList.isEmpty ()) {
            return;
        }

        // check if the whatsapp message EditText field is filled with text and ending with your suffix (explanation above)
        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat messageField = messageNodeList.get (0);
        if (messageField.getText () == null || messageField.getText ().length () == 0 
            || !messageField.getText ().toString ().endsWith (getApplicationContext ().getString (R.string.whatsapp_suffix))) { // So your service doesn't process any message, but the ones ending your apps suffix
            return;
        }

        // Whatsapp send button id
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> sendMessageNodeInfoList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId ("com.whatsapp:id/send");
        if (sendMessageNodeInfoList == null || sendMessageNodeInfoList.isEmpty ()) {
            return;
        }

        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat sendMessageButton = sendMessageNodeInfoList.get (0);
        if (!sendMessageButton.isVisibleToUser ()) {
            return;
        }

        // Now fire a click on the send button
        sendMessageButton.performAction (AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);

        // Now go back to your app by clicking on the Android back button twice: 
        // First one to leave the conversation screen 
        // Second one to leave whatsapp
        try {
            Thread.sleep (500); // hack for certain devices in which the immediate back click is too fast to handle
            performGlobalAction (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
            Thread.sleep (500);  // same hack as above
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        performGlobalAction (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
    }
}
```

Then create its definition in `res -> xml -> whatsapp_service.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"/>
```

Then declare it in your manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.WhatsappAccessibilityService"
    android:label="Accessibility Service"
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/whatsapp_service"/>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And last thing, is to check if the accessibility services are enabled for your app or not, and redirect the user to the settings if not:

```
private boolean isAccessibilityOn (Context context, Class<? extends AccessibilityService> clazz) {
    int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
    final String service = context.getPackageName () + "/" + clazz.getCanonicalName ();
    try {
        accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt (context.getApplicationContext ().getContentResolver (), Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException ignored) {  }

    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter colonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter (":");

    if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString (context.getApplicationContext ().getContentResolver (), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        if (settingValue != null) {
            colonSplitter.setString (settingValue);
            while (colonSplitter.hasNext ()) {
                String accessibilityService = colonSplitter.next ();

                if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase (service)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

which you'll call with:

```
if (!isAccessibilityOn (context, WhatsappAccessibilityService.class)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
    context.startActivity (intent);
}
```

---

This is purely on the technical aspect of the solution.

Now, the ethical question of **"should you do that?"**, I believe the answer is quite clear:

Except if you are targeting people with disabilities (which is the very purpose of the Accessibility API), you should probably **NOT** do that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.. don't worry, the app is to detect power losses, insteed of sms we decided to use whatsapp.. i tryied your solution, but  the event onAccessibilityEvent  is never get called, onServiceConnected is called thought, can you help me more please.. thank you!

Comment: The event isAccessibilityOn  is working! and detects when i open whatsapp, but the send function doesn't work

Comment: @Nizar check the suffix part of your message.

Comment: @Nizar put some logs on all the conditions in the code above, and see where it quits so we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Nizar, glad I could be of some help. Btw, you'll notice that I'm using `AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat` of the support library and ***NOT*** `AccessibilityNodeInfo` for this exact reason. :)

Comment: I'm testing on a old phone below API 18, which is required by AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat to function, it's strange that Android Studio didn't flag a warning ;) is there other options to make it work with JELLY_BEAN version? Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: It works. Just I am getting null on findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId after which it stops sending message. Out of 10 I am able to send 3-4 contacts only. Can anyone check on it.

Comment: @HarshalBennake Can You help to solve the probelm? i apply this solution but its work with debug mode only. not direct run of application from android studio.

Comment: This works perfect, only issue is when that contact is not having whatsapp account, it stucks

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya hey are you able to solve this?? i know its too late now

Comment: and whats the suffix com.whatsapp??

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya bro can you help me on this !!

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya sent bro

Comment: Can someone send the source code and how to use this code??

Comment: How can I start the service. There is not the `startService()` method.

Comment: Message not sent on business account ,How could i do . Please Help, Thanks. above code working perfectly in normal whatsApp.

Comment: Is this achievable in Flutter?

Comment: I have done everything above, but nothing happened and the service not working at all.
Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Does this still work in 2023?

Comment: @JayVDiyk Technically yes, if you integrate the native modules in it.

Comment: @Harshal Benake, I run into this issue too... so, in the poc about this... i made a workaround using: 
try {
     <here is where the exception raises>
}catch (Exception e){ return; }

And now, after send msg in wap, returns to the app without failing.